# How to read row details of a GuiTree control using GUI Script

Tags: automation, vbscript, rpa, sap-gui

I need to read a specific column value of the last row of the below Variant table in SAP GUI. When I record the script to navigate through the rows of the table, I get below lines. I need to extract specific cell value. Manually, I can copy and paste the content of the row to note pad. But, I am unable to figure out how to read the content of the specific column or entire row.

I have been trying different ways:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subTABSTRIP:SAPLATAB:0100/tabsTABSTRIP100/tabpTAB06/" _
    & "ssubSUBSC:SAPLATAB:0201/subAREA1:SAPLAIA1:0304/subSUB:SAPLAIA1:0308/" _
    & "subTREE:SAPLAIA1:0306/cntlVARI_CANVAS/shell").selectedNode = "0001"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subTABSTRIP:SAPLATAB:0100/tabsTABSTRIP100/tabpTAB06/" _
    & "ssubSUBSC:SAPLATAB:0201/subAREA1:SAPLAIA1:0304/subSUB:SAPLAIA1:0308/" _
    & "subTREE:SAPLAIA1:0306/cntlVARI_CANVAS/shell").selectedNode = "0002"
```

These are the lines generated when I move down the row using down arrow key. But how can I get the content of the row?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a [`GuiTree`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/760.00/en-US/8f08be87b0194d9882d0382eae798617.html) object, and more specifically one of type "Column Tree".

In your case, that will be:

```
set tree = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subTABSTRIP:SAPLATAB:0100/tabsTABSTRIP100/tabpTAB06/" _
& "ssubSUBSC:SAPLATAB:0201/subAREA1:SAPLAIA1:0304/subSUB:SAPLAIA1:0308/" _
& "subTREE:SAPLAIA1:0306/cntlVARI_CANVAS/shell")
```

The property `SelectedNode` gives a String which is the key of the node currently selected ("node" is for a line of the tree):

```
nodeKey = tree.SelectedNode
```

From there, you may access the node text with the method `GetNodeText`:

```
nodeText = tree.GetNodeText( nodekey )
```

The text of a cell is obtained with the method `GetItemText` ("item" being a cell at the intersection of a row and a column of the tree, excluding the left column containing the hierarchy):

```
itemText = tree.GetItemText( nodeKey, columnName )`
```

The column names are obtained with the method `GetColumnNames`:

```
set columnNames = tree.GetColumnNames()`
```

The column names being a [GuiComponentCollection](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/760.00/en-US/efae49c2953b43ccb902431ccc9b19d1.html) object, you loop at its elements as follows:

```
for i = 0 to columnNames.Length - 1
  colunmName = columnNames.ElementAt(i)
next
```